# Running method in the background and UI Thread WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, task-parallel-library, task

I'm having troubles with the following example:

```
public void Method()
{
  LongRunningMethod();
}
```

`LongRunningMethod()` takes around 5 seconds to invoke. I am invoking `Method()` from the UI thread, so it obviously should freeze the UI. The solution for that is to run `Method()` within a new `Task` so I am running it like this:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>{Method()})
```

It's still blocking the UI so I thought whether `LongRunningMethod()` is using the UI context probably. Then I tried another solution:

`new Thread(()=>Method()).Start()`

and it started working. How is that possible? I know that `Task` is not guaranteed to be run on a different thread but `CLR` should be smart enough to figure out that it's long running method.

Comment: Have you tried Task.Run(()=>{Method}); ? Is it still freezing UI? Is LongRunningMethod updates UI? Is there ObservableCollections in longRuningMethod()? read the article about Task.Run vs Task.Factory.New() http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html

Comment: No it doesn't update UI - at least it shouldn't, it's an external library.

Comment: is it your external library? Have you seen code? CLR cannot use UI thread, cause dispatcher directs Task to free thread from ThreadPool.

Comment: no it's not mine. What I think is making the issue is that Method is run from another task which uses task scheduler UI so It's inheriting scheduler, is that correct?

Comment: I do not think so, it is not possible. It would be real fault. Read what MSDN says **cause  the work is put on this shared queue and eventually de-queued onto the next thread that becomes available** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997402(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: See next post for more detailed scenario

Comment: Would a background worker work for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are scheduling work on the User Interface (UI) Thread cause you are using
    `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext())` in this code:

```
Task nextTask = task.ContinueWith(x =>
   {
       DoSomething();
   }, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

       task.Start();
     }
```

And this is a reason why your UI is frozen. To prevent try to change `TaskScheduler` to `Default`:

```
Task task = Task.Run(() => {; });
Task nextTask = task.ContinueWith(x =>
{
   //DoSomething();
}, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion, TaskScheduler.Default);
```

[`Task.Factory.StartNew` is dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html) cause it uses `TaskScheduler.Current` as opposed to `TaskScheduler.Default`. To prevent this use `Task.Run` which always points to `TaskScheduler.Default`. `Task.Run` is new in .NET 4.5, if you're in .NET 4.0 you can create your `TaskFactory` with default parameters.

[As MSDN says:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997394(v=vs.110).aspx)

> `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext())` means schedule
>   a task on the same thread that the user interface (UI) control was
>   created on.

**Update:**

What happens when you run method RunTask():

1. `var task = new Task(action, cancellationTokenSource.Token);`

   create a "task". (task is not run. The "task" is just queed to the ThreadPool.)
2. `Task nextTask = task.ContinueWith(x =>
           {
               DoSomething();
           }, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());`

create a "nextTask" which will start performing AFTER "task" is completed and the "nextTask" will be performed on UI thread as you've set a feature 
`TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`.

3. `task.Start();`

You run your "task". When the "task" is completed, then "nextTask" is run by method "task.ContinuuWith()" which will be performed on UI thread you wrote `(TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`

So to sum up, the two your tasks are interconnected and continuation of `task` is performed on UI thread which is a reason to freeze your UI. To prevent this behavior use `TaskScheduler.Default`.

Comment: Yes but if you notice that I am not invoking LongRunningMethod inside nextTask but inside task which is not created using UI taskscheduler but Task constructor.

Comment: This is the flow: task -> nextTask(UI scheduler) -> task created inside nextTask (call it LongTask). Because LongTask is created in nextTask which was scheduled to run on UI thread it means that it will use the same scheduler - in this case UI scheduler? Is that correct?

Comment: @Zbigniew yes, but `Task nextTask = task.ContinueWith(x =>` is not creating new `Task`. It is just a creation new variable type of `Task`. To create new `Task` or any other object, then C# uses keyword `new`.

Comment: Yes but you don't see my point. I am trying to explain that if you notice there is a recurrencial call to RunTask. After reading this post: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html everything is clear. thank you

Comment: @Zbigniew you mean you are creating new Task at `if (condition) 
    RunTask(() => Method());` block?

Comment: We are in nextTask using UI scheduler then If condition is true then we are running RunTask again so new Task(action, cancellationTokenSource.Token) is created using UI scheduler because I assume that Task.Factory.StartNew and new Task(...) use current scheduler which in this case is UI. So if we don't want to have this behaviour we need to change new Task(...) into Task.Run which by default uses default scheduler.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly how it looks like:

```
 public void RunTask(Action action){
   var task = new Task(action, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
 Task nextTask = task.ContinueWith(x =>
   {
       DoSomething();
   }, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

       task.Start();
     }

public void DoSomething()
{
    if(condition) // condition is true in this case (it's recurency but not permanent)
    RunTask(() => Method()); // method is being passed which blocks UI when invoked in RunTask method
}

public void Method()
{
  LongRunningMethod();
}
```

This is the starting point invocation (UI Thread):

```
  RunTask(()=>Action());
```

Answer (score 0):

Only a guess: `Thread.Start` creates a foreground thread. Maybe the method switches to a known foreground-thread when it detects, that it is run from a background-thread.

Hope it helps somehow.